# Java macros in android code

Tags: java, android, macros

I'm reading some code in bigger project and i've found something like this in custom activity (`CustomActivity extends Activity` ):

```
    @Target({ TYPE, FIELD })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface ServiceListener {
        Class<? extends AService> service();

        int[] property();
    }

    @Target({ TYPE, FIELD })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface ServiceListeners {
        ServiceListener[] value();
    }
```

Then it is used to add service listeners to service .
Then i have next Activity (`DetailActivity extends CustomActivity`) where i have something like this:

```
@ServiceListeners({@ServiceListener(service = Service.class, property = Properties.SOME_PROPERTY)})
public class ClusterActivity extends CustomActivity implements AServiceListener , OnClickListener{...}
```

This macro registers service listener? There is no code like `service.addServiceListener(this)` or something like this to register new listener for service. This macro do this automatically? Can I add more than one property that i want to listen to using this macro?

Comment: These aren't _macros_; these are [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).

Comment: Ok, Annotations, i'll read about it. Can I register more than one listener per object using this Annotations? If yes, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's some [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) library being used that processes the `@` annotations and runs some repetitive code based on them, making the code less coupled and easier to test.

> Can I register more than one listener per object using this Annotations? If yes, how.

Generally, to include multiple values in an annotation, put the values in `{}` and separate by `,`. For example:

```
@FooAnnotation({ value1, value2 })
```

So the following probably works:

```
@ServiceListeners({@ServiceListener(service = Service.class, property = Properties.SOME_PROPERTY),
    @ServiceListener(service = AnotherService.class, property = Properties.ANOTHER_PROPERTY)})
```